# IIS URL Rewrite - Convert POST to GET

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7.5, http-post, http-get

In my application there is a client and a WCf REST service. For invoking some wcf service the client is doing an http POST even though the service is a GET.

i do not want to do any changes in the client or the service.

So is there a way where i can convert this POST request to GET and add the data coming in as the POST to the URL and invoke the REST service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use URL Rewrite to issue 3xx Redirect which will use GET method, but you will loose all POST data.

The only **safe way** known to me is to **rewrite POST request to some another custom page**, where you:

- collect all POST data/variables;
- convert them into GET variables (assemble proper GET request);
- issue 301 (or 302) Redirect to the proper URL (it will have all POST data sent as GET variables).

Such rewrite to custom page should be easy -- you need to check what method is used (POST or GET) and only invoke it on POST. The rest will be handled in that post-to-get script.

The reason for all of this complexity is the difference in how POST and GET requests work: with GET all data is sent as part of URL while POST uses request body to transfer variable's data.

Comment: Is there anyway of doing this using Custom HttpHandlers?

Comment: Maybe -- Unfortunately I'm not a .NET guy to advise you on this in that direction.